# Sending JSON message to web api via post. Why does HTTP 1.0 versus 1.1 make a difference?

Tags: programming, tcpip, web-service, json

I am sending a message to a web api call every xx seconds. I could not get it to work at all until I changed the header from HTTP 1.1 which is what I was using to HTTP 1.0. Then, it started working. Why would this affect things where I could not post and now I can?

This is what it was when it wasn't working:

```
client.println("POST /BoxLevel/api/BoxMeasurement HTTP/1.1");
```

And the change that fixed it:

```
client.println("POST /BoxLevel/api/BoxMeasurement HTTP/1.0");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 requires you to provide the host name of the server. And it will keep the connection open for some time unless you explicitly opt out of this. Thus, the equivalent of the basic HTTP/1.0 request in HTTP/1.1 language is

```
POST /the_uri HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.example.com
Connection: close
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One follow up question, with the host requirement in 1.1, does the host have to be valid? Meaning, will the client try to resolve the connection or check the host or can you populate it with anything?

Comment: @MichaelBedford: It's up to the server to interpret the `Host` header. It is very common for a single server to serve more than one Web site (it's called [shared hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service)). The `Host` header is then used by the server to know which Web site the client wants. If you provide an empty or a dummy name, you usually get a useless dummy page. A server serving a single site may just ignore that header, but it could also give an error if it's incorrect.